# Python Library/Module for (simple) Undirected Graphs

Tags: python, graph, python-3.x, python-module

I've been searching the web for the past hour trying to find a library for python that will help me create and draw simple undirected graphs. It looks like NetworkX (http://networkx.lanl.gov/index.html) is by far the most popular one but unfortunately it doesn't support drawing for Python 3.

Any suggestions? I don't need anything super powerful or complex, just basic (even undirected) graph creation and drawing (and maybe exporting as png, jpeg, etc). You know, just a few nodes and edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetworkX mentions quite a few ways to [draw graphs](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/drawing.html) using [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [python-graph](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/wiki/Example) library? It is a library and you can use it to draw graphs as you might find it useful. Simple Undirected Graphs is very much possible. I see that they mention about [Python3.1 support](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/wiki/Installation) too. It uses Graphviz to you export it to pngs. (I am unable to find out its py3k support)

Answer (score 0):

Google Chart has (ugly) Graphviz support nowadays, maybe that can work?

GChartWrapper is a good API that runs on Python 3, so check that out. Otherwise you can just make calls with urllib...

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/GChartWrapper/

Comment: Looks interesting, still it's quite strange that there is not even a single graph on their "examples" section. I'll give it a try later/tomorrow and I will update you.